# Cannot access GCP projects anymore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-account

my development team has been sparingly trying out Google Cloud Platform for about 10 months. Every member was using the same account to access GCP, say *team@example.com*. We created three projects under this account.

Starting in about July, we cannot see these projects in the GCP console anymore. Instead, there is one project named *My First Project*, which we have never created.

However, our original GCP projects still seem to exist, as we can still access for example some of the Google Cloud Functions via HTTP.

Therefore, I have the impression that the connection between our account and the projects has been lost.
OR
A second account with the same name has been accidentally created?

Additional curiosities:

1. Yesterday I tried to create a Google Cloud Identity account, using *team@example.com*. It did not work; when entering that address the input field showed an error like "Please use another email address. This is a private Google account." (It was actually in German, so I'm guessing the translation.)
2. When I go to accounts.google.com, the account selection screen offers *team@example.com* twice. No matter which entry I choose, I always end up in the GCP console with *My First Project*.

How can I recover my team's GCP projects?

Which Google support site may I consult to check on the account(s)?

Comment: Go to your Google Payment account. This will show you the projects linked to your account.  https://payments.google.com/ If the projects do not appear, double check what credit card was used to pay for your GCP services. Then contact Google Clud Billing Support in the Cloud Console under Support.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, there is a 1:1 mapping between a certain email address and a Google Account. However, this can be broken under certain situations - for example when creating / deleting / migrating G Suite or Cloud Identity accounts under the domain the email address uses.

If you hit such an edge case, there's not much you can do yourself. Reach out to GCP Support who should be able to resolve the issue for you.

Keep in mind that orphaned resources have a timer on them before they are deleted - so act quickly and do not rely on apps still responding being a sign that they will continue indefinitely.